# rsync not writing files

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync

I'm trying to setup rsync to backup a remote directory to my local drive.

I cd to the directory that I want to pull the files to, then I enter:

```
rsync -vrtW account@remote.com:~/public_html
```

I enter the password then it starts running. I get all the files listed, but none of them actually transfer. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's really your commandline, the [rsync manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/) has your answer:

> SYNOPSIS
>    Local:  rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]
>
> Access via remote shell:
>      Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST:SRC... [DEST]
>      Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST:DEST
>
> [...]
>
> **Usages with just one SRC arg and no DEST arg will list the source files instead of copying.**

Note the last line.  This is the command you need to use (note the **"."** at the end).

```
rsync -vrtW account@remote.com:~/public_html .
```